# How to prove $X$~$B(n,p)$ and $Y$~$B(m,p)$?

Tags: probability, random-variables, binomial-distribution

Assuming $X$ and $Y$ are random variables with non-negative integer values, and they are independent. $\forall x,y \in N^+$, we have $P(X=x| \ X+Y=x+y)=\frac{\binom{m}{x}\binom{n}{y}}{\binom{m+n}{x+y}}$, which m,n is positive integer. And $P(X=0)>0, P(Y=0)>0$.

So how to prove  $X$~$B(n,p)$ and $Y$~$B(m,p)$ now?

Both attempts have failed and I'm not quite sure what else to try. Any help would vastly appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to add your attempts, even if they have failed.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint* Use the formula which says that if random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $f_{X|Y=y}(x,y)=\frac{f_{XY}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}.$

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little bit? I know $f_{X|Y=y}(x,y)=\frac{f_{XY}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}$ is the conditional probability formula and I can't understand how it relates to independence. Very grateful to you.

Comment: @Swaggey, you ought to check if random variables $X$ and $X+Y$ are independent in your case. You can do this by eg. checking if $$E(X(X+Y))=E(X)E(X+Y).$$ Of course there are also many other methods, but this is one of them.

Comment: OK , I will try it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Swaggey  Novice's hint says$$\mathsf P(X{=}x\mid X{+}Y{=}x{+}y)=\dfrac{\mathsf P(X{+}Y{=}x{+}y, X{=}x)}{\mathsf P(X{+}Y{=}x{+}y)}$$

Comment: I don't see how this helps. Did you read the question? And why would one check if $X$ and $X+Y$ are independent?(they are clearly not)

Comment: $X$ and $X+Y$ are not independent.  $X$ and $Y$ are.

Comment: I had a hope that they are - unfortunately I haven't checked it. My mistake.